# React routing does not work after building the build with Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I'm working on a blog website like app. I have used react router to serve the root page and the sign-up page. When I run the app using vite in development environment I can navigate to sign-up page by going to /sign-up. But when I create the build and run with live server I cannot naviate to the /sign-up, I got **Cannot GET /sign-up.**

**What I've tried**

I've read somewhere that I need to configure the vite to serve the index.html file for client side routing. I don't exactly know how to do it still. I find out about **historyApiFallback** and set it to **true** but it did not worked.

I am expecting that when I navigate to /sign-up it will render the component that is given.

Here is the vite configuration:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    test: {
        globals: true,

        environment: "jsdom",

        setupFiles: "./setupTests.js",
    },
    server: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
});
```

That is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "bashnode",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build",
        "lint": "eslint src --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "test": "vitest",
        "coverage": "vitest run --coverage"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.11.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.0.0",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "eslint": "^8.38.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^4.0.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
        "jsdom": "^22.0.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.23",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
        "vite": "^4.3.2",
        "vitest": "^0.31.1"
    }
}
```

And that is my react code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Root from "./routes/root";
import ErrorPage from "./error-page";
import SignUp from "./routes/sign-up";
import "./index.css";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Root />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    },
    {
        path: "/sign-up",
        element: <SignUp />,
        errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I've post the relevant code, full code can be found here: https://github.com/muditchoudhary/BashNode

Comment: You need to configure your web server to serve index.html on all routes that belong to the SPA. How you do that depends on how you're serving the build on your server.

Comment: Check the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to see if there's a relevant section applicable to where/how you are deploying your app and serving it.

Comment: @Mudit did you find a solution for this?